# Is it a bad thing to send an application for a master thesis late at night?

Tags: etiquette, application, job-search

I am looking at an advertised Masters thesis/internship that could lead to a PhD. The first contact should be made by email.

Is there any chance it could be looked down upon if I send that first email late at night?

I live (and currently study) in the same timezone as that of the research group, and that will be made evident by the contents of my first email.

Comment: Apart from etiquette, you should do your final review and transmit of an important e-mail at a time when you are as alert as possible. One of the common themes here is "I made mistake X in my application. What should I do about it?", where X can be something like putting the wrong college name in a cover letter.

Comment: I doubt anyone will notice really.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Officially and practically, no. Applicants often worry about things that faculty hardly have time to even think through. Your application is understandably your central focus but it can't be the faculty's with the same level of attention.

In a nutshell, on the faculty side, I really can't imagine a colleague would care about that unless there were instructions for the time etc.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the application arrives on time, you do not need to worry. Sometimes, there are hard cut-off times on the advertisement, stating time and timezone; that is an indication that you need to be on time.

Apart from that, nobody would bother about the time you send it anyway. After all, you could be logged in from anywhere in the world when you send off your mail.